# Re-Adding views to a fragment on onResume returns an IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application with fragments.

I've seen that only two fragments are on memory at the same time. When I show a third one, first one calls `onDestroyView`.

I add `EditText` to fragment's view programmatically. Those `EditText` don't show again after fragment's view recreation on `onResume` method.

I use those `EditText` to let users add data to a form and I store a reference in `firstTable` `HashMap`. I will use that `HashMap` to retrieve user's values.

Here I create those `EditText` programmatically:

```
private LinearLayout createNewFirstTableRow(long articleId)
{
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mActivity);
    LayoutParams parentParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);
    parentParams.weight = 1;
    layout.setLayoutParams(parentParams);

    if (firstTable == null)
        firstTable = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<EditText>>();

    ArrayList<EditText> fields = new ArrayList<EditText>(7);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0, 40);
    params.weight = 0.125f;

    TextView textView = new TextView(mActivity);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText(new Long(articleId).toString());
    layout.addView(textView);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        EditText edit = new EditText(mActivity);
        edit.setLayoutParams(params);
        edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        fields.add(i, edit);
        layout.addView(edit);
    }

    firstTable.put(new Long(articleId), fields);

    return layout;
}
```

`firstTable` variable is a global variable: `private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<EditText>> firstTable;`.

To add my `EditText` I do the following on `onResume`:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    Log.v("QuantityFragment", "onResume: " + firstTableRowIndex);

    if ((firstTable != null) && (secondTable != null))
    {
        firstTableRowIndex = FIRST_TABLE_ROW_INDEX;
        secondTableRowIndex = SECOND_TABLE_ROW_INDEX;

        LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.quantityTable);

        for (int index = 0; index < firstTable.size(); index++)
        {
            Long articleId = articleIds.get(index);

            table.addView(resumeTable(articleId, secondTable.get(articleId)), secondTableRowIndex);
            table.addView(resumeTable(articleId, firstTable.get(articleId)), firstTableRowIndex);

            firstTableRowIndex++;
            secondTableRowIndex++;
        }
    }

    super.onResume();
}

private LinearLayout resumeTable(Long articleId, ArrayList<EditText> fields)
{
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mActivity);
    LayoutParams parentParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);
    parentParams.weight = 1;
    layout.setLayoutParams(parentParams);


    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0, 40);
    params.weight = 0.125f;

    TextView textView = new TextView(mActivity);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText(new Long(articleId).toString());
    layout.addView(textView);

    for (int index = 0; index < fields.size(); index++)
    {
        layout.addView(fields.get(index));
    }

    return layout;
}
```

But, here `layout.addView(textView);` I get an exception:

**IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

Is there another way to re-add those `EditText`?

**UPDATE:**

I have solved my problem changing `resumeTable`:

```
private LinearLayout resumeTable(Long articleId, ArrayList<EditText> fields)
{
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mActivity);
    LayoutParams parentParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);
    parentParams.weight = 1;
    layout.setLayoutParams(parentParams);


    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0, 40);
    params.weight = 0.125f;

    TextView textView = new TextView(mActivity);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText(new Long(articleId).toString());
    layout.addView(textView);

    for (int index = 0; index < fields.size(); index++)
    {
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)fields.get(index).getParent();
        parent.removeView(fields.get(index));
        layout.addView(fields.get(index));
    }

    return layout;
}
```

This is the important part:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < fields.size(); index++)
    {
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)fields.get(index).getParent();
        parent.removeView(fields.get(index));
        layout.addView(fields.get(index));
    }
```

**The question is open, if you have a better solution, please, let me know.**

Answer (score 2):

That exception is thrown because you store references to `Views`(the `EditText`) that were added to the layout and then later you're again re-adding those `Views` to a newly constructed parent.

Regarding a solution, I don't know why you decided to store references to those `EditTexts`. The only data that I see worth storing from those `EditTexts` is the text entered by the user, in which case you should store that text instead of that particular `EditText` .Your method would be:

```
//...
if (firstTable == null) {
    // your HashMap now stores text instead of an EditText
    firstTable = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<String>>();// store only the text from the EditText
}

    ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0, 40);
    params.weight = 0.125f;

    TextView textView = new TextView(mActivity);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText(new Long(articleId).toString());
    layout.addView(textView);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        EditText edit = new EditText(mActivity);
        edit.setLayoutParams(params);
        edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        fields.add(i, ""); // the EditText are empty at first
        layout.addView(edit);
    }
    firstTable.put(new Long(articleId), fields);
```

Then when is time to restore the `EditTexts`:

```
private LinearLayout resumeTable(Long articleId, ArrayList<String> fields) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mActivity);
    LayoutParams parentParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);
    parentParams.weight = 1;
    layout.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0, 40);
    params.weight = 0.125f;
    TextView textView = new TextView(mActivity);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText(new Long(articleId).toString());
    layout.addView(textView);
    for (int index = 0; index < fields.size(); index++) {
        // create new EditTexts
        EditText edit = new EditText(mActivity);
        edit.setLayoutParams(params);
        edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        edit.setText(fields.get(index)); // get the text coresponding to this particular EditText
        layout.addView(edit);
    }
    return layout;
}
```

Of course when the user enters something in the `EditTexts` you should store it in the `firstTable` variable at the right position.

Comment: I need those `EditText` references because I don't how many `EditText` will be and if users clicks on save button I will need to get what user has put on those `EditText`. So, your answer is great but I can't use it.

Comment: @VansFannel If you store the text from the `EditText` like in my answer, then you already know how many `EditText` you have, you just have to see how many strings are in the `ArrayList` from the `firstTable` variable.

Comment: Maybe, I haven't explain it well. I don't know how many EditText will be and I don't know how to get what user has write down on all of them. So, I need a reference to each one to get their value when user taps on save button.

Comment: @VansFannel Could you add the code that runs when the user clicks the save `Button`?

Answer (score 0):

I think problen is due to adding the element of fields twice

```
 ArrayList<EditText> fields = new ArrayList<EditText>(7);
```

1 - in createNewFirstTableRow

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        EditText edit = new EditText(mActivity);
        edit.setLayoutParams(params);
        edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        fields.add(i, edit);//<-----------
        layout.addView(edit);//<----------- added in layout 
    }
```

2- onResume()->resumeTable

```
for (int index = 0; index < fields.size(); index++)
    {
        layout.addView(fields.get(index));//<----------------
    }
```

when fields element alreay added on the screen you can't add that twice.......

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the problem. After fragment's onDestroyView its view is destroyed. When user comes back to fragment all views dynamically added disappear and I'm trying to find a way to add those views again on onResume. But, those views was added to fragment's view and I can't add them again. This is my problem: I don't know how to re-add those EditText added previously.